# Getting access to accounts I don't recognize in Metamask

Tags: metamask

What is happening? It´'s been two times I get access to accounts that are not mine on Metamask. I just paste my recovery phrase (or what I think is my recover phrase) and boom. Once it gave me access to like 10 accounts and the second time to an empty account that I really don´'t think is mine.

Answer (score 2):

A private key and a seed phrase are two different things.
While an address only has one private key and together they make up one externally owned account, many of these pairs can be derived from a single seed phrase.

If you used the 12/24 word recovery phrase in Metamask, it will have shown you a list of the public keys with an option to scroll for more, so you could add the one's you were using.

[image]
https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/4404722782107-User-Guide-Secret-Recovery-Phrase-password-and-private-keys